# Dividor with text and round cornered tables in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do the following layout in Android:

[image: Layout]

My two questions are:

- Is it possible to do a dividor with text without using an image?
- I know that I want to use the `TableLayout` for the registration form, but is it possible to do a round cornered border around the table?

Comment: yes and yes, first one is easy peasy, and second one is a bit more harder, I suggest you if you are spanish or can speak spanish to check this link http://blog.intelligenia.com/2012/02/programacion-movil-en-android.html#more, if not try using google translate :) good luck

Comment: if the first one is easy peasy, how would I do it please?

Comment: sure, give me a moment

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions is yes.

You will want to investigate [Nine-patch drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) for both. 
Nine-patch drawables allow you to create a bitmap and specify where the bitmap will stretch.

As an example with your table, you will have images that look like the the table's top and bottom cells, and you will mark the center of the cells (along the straight edges) as the stretchable area. The rounded edges will stay the same, but the centers will stretch to accommodate the content.